# badges: current status

Tags: feature-request, badges

I was thinking that user in Physics.SE or other SE sites should know the current status for their eligibility for a badge.

For eg. say the gold badge [Marshall](https://physics.stackexchange.com/badges/82/marshal), which has a silver counterpart [Deputy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/badges/67/deputy). But as i don't know the my current status that after how many useful flags, I need more to get the badge.

Can such a feature be enabled in SE sites? I believe such a thing will be able to push users further to achieve their target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only just realized this, but if you hover over the progress badge of a review task, a "badge progress" pop-up appears:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking "Why is this popu-up appearing here and obstructing all the text" and trying to get rid of it when I realised it was an image. : ).

Answer (score 3):

In additon to dmckee's post, it's always better to have an air of mystery around the badges. Otherwise, you'll end up working for the badges instead of the posts. Strive for the badges, but don't obsess about them. If you want a badge, work towards it, not for the badge, but for the site. The badge will follow on it's own :)

Comment: aaahhh..that was a draconian argument... :P

Answer (score 2):

Variations of this request [have been made on the mother meta many times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=badge%20progress) (or I'd migrate this there because this request is not specific to physics).

If you hunt around on [the Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/), you will find queries to report your progress on many badges, though I don't know if Deputy and Marshal are something that can be found that way.

For Deputy and Marshal in particular, your [user profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4887/vineet-menon) shows how many helpful flags you have made:

[image]

Comment: okay helpful flag's are shown but that was just an example..there's a badge for number of edits, there's one for comments...and a lots of others as well..

Comment: @VineetMenon: That is where the data explorer comes in...

Comment: aha...your second edit was helpful...thx...

Comment: @dmckee, I can't seem to find my progress towards Strunk & White in any review sidebar. Did this feature get suppressed? If so, then shouldn't this answer be ammended?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Don't know. They have been tinkering with the review tools. I'll try to find out. Come to think of it, they've completely changed the layout of those tool since I wrote the above. I'll remove it and suggest that you try the data explorer.